# simple javascript code to calculate a countdown

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to edit following code to get the output I want.

```js
function zoo_countdown_end_day() {
    if ($('.zoo-get-order-notice .end-of-day')[0]) {
        var offset = $('.end-of-day').data('timezone');
        var day = new Date();
        var utc = day.getTime() + (day.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
        let d = new Date(utc + (3600000*offset)),
        duration = 60 * (60 - d.getMinutes());
        let timer = duration, minutes;
        let hours = (23 - d.getHours());//kumudu edited this
        hours = hours < 10 ? '0' + hours : hours;
        let label_h = $('.zoo-get-order-notice .end-of-day').data('hours');
        let label_m = $('.zoo-get-order-notice .end-of-day').data('minutes');
        setInterval(function () {
            minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
            minutes = minutes < 10 ? "1" + minutes : minutes;
            $('.zoo-get-order-notice .end-of-day').text(hours + ' ' + label_h + ' ' + minutes + ' ' + label_m);
            if (--timer < 0) {
                timer = duration;
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
}
zoo_countdown_end_day();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="zoo-get-order-notice">
    <span class="end-of-day"
          data-timezone="+3"
          data-hours="1"
          data-minutes="3"></span>
</div>
```

This is the current output:

[image]

I just want to edit countdown time to countdown from next day 4.00 P.M (hours and minuets). Because I offer next day shipping.

Comment: so you want to turn `12 hours 26 minutes` into `Tomorrow 4:00 pm`?

Comment: `could you give an example of desired output?` is my question

Comment: @TheBombSquad Yes. 12 hours 26 minutes + 16 hours will be the desired output

Comment: ite after i eat im gonna just make a timestamp to string converter(would measure difference from present day) and you would help me tweak the format since im not sure on that part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the long and short of this answer is that it uses 2 functions to help..

1. `countDown`: this function takes in a function`whileCountingDown`, a number`forHowLong`, then another function`whenFinishedThen`

   `whileCountingDown` being triggered EACH second with the parameter being the amount of time left in seconds

   `forHowLong` is the amount of seconds this countdown will last

   `whenFinishedThen` is a function that activates **AFTER** the countdown is over.. it can be anything(like making a new countdown as well)
2. `timeParse`: this function takes in a number`seconds` and then returns a string that looks like a more human version of time

   *eg:* `timeParse(108010)`, `108010` is 30 hours and 10 seconds, and it would return `"1 day, 6 hours, 0 minutes"`

The combination of these functions are able to have a countdown system working very well.. **I ALSO DO NOT KNOW WHERE YOU GET YOUR FUTURE TIME FROM**,

but if you get it in a *timestamp* format(like `1611860671302`, a value that I copied from `new Date().getTime()` as I was typing this),

the line where you see `30*3600`, replace that line with `((dateStamp-new Date().getTime())/1000).toFixed(0)`

```js
//honestly I don't even see where it's counting down from so i just made a countdown function that works in seconds and scheduled 30 hours from now(from when you run code).. just the format would probably need changing(since i don't know what format you want)
function zoo_countdown_end_day() {
    var elem=$('.zoo-get-order-notice .end-of-day')[0]
    //like I said, I didn't even see where you're taking the future time from but I'll just give a future time the equivalent of +30 hours
    countDown(
      (t)=>elem.innerText=timeParse(t), //every second, remaining time shows in specified element
      30*3600, //seconds equivalent for 30 hours.. if you have a future dateStamp, before the countdown function, let dateStamp=this datestamp you would have, THEN change this line to.. ((dateStamp-new Date().getTime())/1000).toFixed(0)
      ()=>console.log("Timer Complete")
    )
}
zoo_countdown_end_day();



//...............................................................
//time parsing function(takes in seconds and returns a string of a formatted date[this is what can change to change the look])
function timeParse(seconds){
    var words=[
        (num)=>{if(num==1){return("second")}return("seconds")},//this would return a word for seconds
        (num)=>{if(num==1){return("minute")}return("minutes")},//this would return a word for minutes
        (num)=>{if(num==1){return("hour")}return("hours")},//this would return a word for hours
        (num)=>{if(num==1){return("day")}return("days")}//this would return a word for days
    ]
    var timeArr=[seconds]
    if(timeArr[0]>=60){//if seconds >= 1 minute
        timeArr.unshift(Math.floor(timeArr[0]/60))
        timeArr[1]=timeArr[1]%60
    
        if(timeArr[0]>=60){//if minutes >= 1 hour
            timeArr.unshift(Math.floor(timeArr[0]/60))
            timeArr[1]=timeArr[1]%60
      
            if(timeArr[0]>=24){//if hours >= 1 day
                timeArr.unshift(Math.floor(timeArr[0]/24))
                timeArr[1]=timeArr[1]%24
            }
        }
    }
    timeArr=timeArr.reverse()
    .map((a,i)=>`${a} ${words[i](a)}`)
    .reverse() //puts words to values and then reverses it back to correct order
  timeArr.splice(timeArr.length-1,1) //takes out seconds part from being returned leaving days, minutes and hours
  return(timeArr.join(', ')) //a mixture/combination of the forEach formatting(joining numbers with words), what is returned from words array and how they're joined contributes to the formatted look
}
//...............................................................
//countDown function(that works in seconds)
function countDown(whileCountingDown, forHowLong, whenFinishedThen){
    //basic run down is, whileCountingDown is a function, forHowLong is a number, whenFinishedThen is a function
    //in depth run down is:
    /*
    whileCountingDown(with parameter of how much time left in seconds) is activated every second until forHowLong seconds has passed, then whenFinishedThen is triggered
  */
  
    var i=setInterval(()=>{forHowLong--
        if(forHowLong<=0){//count finished, determine what happens next
            clearInterval(i); whenFinishedThen()
        }
        else{whileCountingDown(forHowLong)}//do this for each second of countdown
    },1000)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="zoo-get-order-notice">
    <span class="end-of-day"
          data-timezone="+3"
          data-hours="1"
          data-minutes="3"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Typically giving code without an explanation is a bad practice on stackoverflow. Even I want to know the explanation of this out of the sake of curiosity. Can you please elaborate more on how this works?

Comment: ok.. sry about that :{ still working on the answer.. so lemme explain..

Comment: so I have 3 functions.. 2 that I made and 1 that I left from his code(tbh it doesnt need to be a function really) the `timeParse` function would take in a parameter called *seconds* which is a number representing seconds; eg: `300`. it would take that number and return a string that looks more human like; eg: `0d:0:5:0`.. this function can be changed to change the format of how it displays the `seconds` data it gets

Comment: the `countDown` function takes in 3 parameters: *whileCountingDown* is a function activated every second in the countdown and this function is given the time remaining(in seconds), *forHowLong* is the amount of seconds you want this countdown to take, *whenFinishedThen* is just another function that activates when the countdown is over.. i just brought 2 stuff that i made before and just used them

Comment: Yes, but I recommend formatting the code a little bit more. My brain isn't in it today, so I can't understand it that much (if I *really* tried, maybe), but I definitely recommend indenting your code (especially around the `Array.map` functions and such).